# How to rotate Image

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I'm trying to rotate an Image but couldn't get expected result.
I want rotate image as 90 degree. After executing my code i got unexpected result.
here is my code:

```
public async Task Rotate(string path, Rect rect, float degrees)
    {
        int h = (int)Math.Sqrt(rect.Width * rect.Width + rect.Height * rect.Height);

        CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        CanvasRenderTarget webCardImage = null;
        CanvasBitmap bitmap = null;
        var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
        Vector2 endpoint = new Vector2((float)rect.Width / 2, (float)rect.Height / 2);

        try
        {
            webCardImage = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, h, h, logicalDpi);
            using (var ds = webCardImage.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);

                using (FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    IRandomAccessStream fileStream = imageStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
                    bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, fileStream);
                }

                ICanvasImage image = new Transform2DEffect
                {
                    Source = bitmap,
                    TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(degrees, endpoint),
                };
                var sourceRect = image.GetBounds(ds);
                ds.DrawImage(image, new Rect(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height), sourceRect, 1, CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        //Convert to Image
    }
```

My Code generated Image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, my teammate will reply to you on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297514/rotate-image-in-win2d), you can check it.

Comment: @Faywang - MSFT , oh thats great. i'm checking

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code does, but this code should make the trick

```
BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
bmpImage.BeginInit();
bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Images\Dock.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bmpImage.EndInit();
TransformedBitmap transformBmp = new TransformedBitmap();
transformBmp.BeginInit();
transformBmp.Source = bmpImage;
RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(90);
transformBmp.Transform = transform;
transformBmp.EndInit();
```

This is for WPF application, for Windows Forms application you can see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rotateflip?view=netframework-4.5

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm looking for Win2d, UWP